# How do I upgrade intl extension to ICU 4+ on OS X 10.7 Lion with PHP 5.3.8-ZS5.5.0

Tags: php, icu, zend-server-ce, intl

I am running OS X 10.7 Lion with Zend Server CE 5.5 (and therefore PHP 5.3.8). When I try to setup a new Symfony2 project the configuration checker warns me to upgrade the intl extension to ICU 4+.

I followed the instructions I found in [another StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704083/how-do-i-upgrade-apc-on-zend-community-server-needed-for-symfony2), mainly this blog post about [upgrading intl on Lion](http://mansion.im/2011/php-with-intl-and-gettext-on-osx-lion/). But when I try to compile the extension with PHP 5.3.8. I get the following error:

```
$ make
/bin/sh /Users/Florian/Downloads/php-5.3.8/ext/intl/libtool --mode=compile cc -I/usr/local/include -I. -I/Users/Florian/Downloads/php-5.3.8/ext/intl -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/Florian/Downloads/php-5.3.8/ext/intl/include -I/Users/Florian/Downloads/php-5.3.8/ext/intl/main -I/Users/Florian/Downloads/php-5.3.8/ext/intl -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /Users/Florian/Downloads/php-5.3.8/ext/intl/php_intl.c -o php_intl.lo 
mkdir .libs
cc -I/usr/local/include -I. -I/Users/Florian/Downloads/php-5.3.8/ext/intl -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/Florian/Downloads/php-5.3.8/ext/intl/include -I/Users/Florian/Downloads/php-5.3.8/ext/intl/main -I/Users/Florian/Downloads/php-5.3.8/ext/intl -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /Users/Florian/Downloads/php-5.3.8/ext/intl/php_intl.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/php_intl.o
/Users/Florian/Downloads/php-5.3.8/ext/intl/php_intl.c:490: error: ‘PHP_FE_END’ undeclared here (not in a function)
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
```

I was able to compile intl.so with PHP 5.3.6 but when I put that file in my php_extensions directory, PHP does not recognize intl at all. I think in my last attempt I tried to compile it with ICU 4.0.1, but I also tried some other versions like 4.8.1 or 4.6.1. Is there any possibility to compile ICU with PHP 5.3.8 on 10.7 at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

How much do you need Zend Server? If not at all, then you could try http://php-osx.liip.ch/ which comes with ext/intl and everything else you need for Symfony2