# Upgrade APC to work with Symfony 2 on Zend Server and OSX

Tags: macos, ubuntu, symfony, apc, zend-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade APC on Zend Community Server (needed for Symfony2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704083/how-do-i-upgrade-apc-on-zend-community-server-needed-for-symfony2)

I'm trying to set up a new Symfony 2 Standard Application and it keeps telling me that I need to upgrade my php APC extension.

The thing is, on my Zend Server runnning OSX, I already have the newest version of APC, 3.1.9.

I tested on Ubuntu with the same environment, Zend Server and that same version of APC, and it works fine, so the problem is really on OSX.

Apparently, on OSX the APC extension is built-in Zend Server, while on ubuntu it is not.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix that problem?

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I upgrade APC on Zend Community Server (needed for Symfony2)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7704083/3765)

Comment: Well, turns out the solution to that question was not even a solution. I would like to keep using Zend Server and not switch to MAMP. Any ideas?

Comment: But it doesn't work. Even if you enable or disable how much times you want, Zend Server doesn't recognize any APC extensions set up on php.ini, not as a usual extension, neither as a zend extension.

Comment: Don't take me wrong, but that's not the point. I need to solve that problem.

Comment: Yeah that's a good start, but they don't seem to have an answer yet.

Comment: @leek, it doesn't work, I've already tried that. One question though: how do you enable the PECL APC extension on php.ini? As a zend_extension or a simple extension?

Comment: Do I need to disable the built-in APC extension of Zend Server to do that?

Comment: **FYI:** I have removed my comments and posted everything as an answer.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with the answer on the question this is a duplicate of, you can offer a bounty on *that* question.  There's a specific bounty reason for the reasons you've specified in the comments above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704083/how-do-i-upgrade-apc-on-zend-community-server-needed-for-symfony2/7706894#7706894) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704083/how-do-i-upgrade-apc-on-zend-community-server-needed-for-symfony2) suggests it is as simple as disabling/re-enabling APC.

However, there is an open Symfony issue (#227) [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/227).

I would suggest installing the APC extension separately and try to disable the built-in Zend Server version. If I remember correctly, the order of how extra extensions are loaded in Zend Server's `php.ini` matters.

If you're using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), install APC with [this formula](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/blob/master/Formula/apc-php.rb) and follow the instructions on the installer (enable with `extension` not `zend_extension`). You can try it without disabling the built-in APC, but to avoid conflicts I would disable it.

---

**Update #1:** A couple more things to try:

- Ensure Zend Optimizer+ is disabled.
- Disable Zend Server's "APC Compatibility Mode"
- `zend_optimizer.optimization_level = 0`

---

**Update #2:** Since you need a 32-bit version of APC, try this:

```
cd /usr/local/src
pecl download apc
tar -zxvf APC-*.tgz
cd APC-*
phpize
./configure MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6 CFLAGS="-arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -no-cpp-precomp" CCFLAGS="-arch i386 -g -Os -pipe" CXXFLAGS="-arch i386 -g -Os -pipe" LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -bind_at_load" --enable-apc-debug=no --enable-apc-filehits=no --enable-apc-spinlocks=no --enable-apc-memprotect=no --enable-apc-pthreadmutex=yes --enable-apc-pthreadrwlocks=no
make
make install
```

After finished, try that one on Zend Server.

---

**Update #3:** Check out [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190810115342/http://ralphschindler.com:80/2010/05/12/compiling-gearman-or-anything-for-zend-server-ce-on-snow-leopard) by Ralph Schindler on "Compiling Gearman (or anything) for Zend Server CE on Snow Leopard". And [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200925025910/http://www.worldgoneweb.com/2011/zendserver-community-edition-on-mac-os-x-compiling-php-extensions/) is one more. Perhaps there is something different in the './configure' commands from those articles that will work for you.

Comment: I'm at work right now, so I'm gonna try this out at the end of the day and get back to you. Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Turns out this solution doesn't work. I've tried in a number ways and I have nothing. The Formula downloads the APC from pecl and the activation of it on php.ini doesn't get recognize by Zend Server.

Comment: @drgomesp: Have you disable the Zend Optimizer? You cannot run both of them together.

Comment: What I get now is the following message on the extensions panel: The system could not load this extension. Log message shows: /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/apc.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Turns out the error is caused by the extension being compiled on x86_64, and Zend Server CE only works with i386 ones. My problem now is to discover how to compile apc to i386.

Comment: @drgomesp: The problem is more likely that you have the wrong version of Zend Server for your architecture. When you installed APC through homebrew, it was compiled for you (see [here](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/blob/master/Formula/apc-php.rb)). Try downloading a different version of Zend Server that is `x86_64`.

Comment: I can't really read .rb, but I can see with the file command that the apc.so is generated as x86_64 arch, when all the extensions that come with Zend Server are i386. Can't I adapt that code with something to compile it as i386? Zend Server doesn't have a x86_64 version for OSX...

Comment: @drgomesp: Try my latest update to the answers

Comment: Trying to manually compile like you said on edit 2, I got this message on the logs: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apc: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @drgomesp: Looks like you ran `phpize` from the version of PHP that is installed with OSX and not the version that is installed with Zend Server. If you run `which php` and it doesn't point to Zend Server's `phpize` then try re-running it with an absolute path.

Comment: I did figure that out and then tried to run `phpize` from the `/usr/local/zend/bin` path. Still the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I've run out of ideas, the only thing I could say is to try and download another version of APC from [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC) and see if that will work. Go back to `3.1.6` and try that.

Comment: Same error =/. Guess I'm gonna have to head to MAMP. Thanks a lot for your help though!

Comment: Homebrew can install everything you need. Check out [homebrew-alt](https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt) for [Apache](https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/blob/master/duplicates/httpd.rb) and [homebrew-php](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php) for [PHP](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/blob/master/Formula/php.rb).

Comment: @drgomesp: Also see my 3rd update

Comment: About homebrew, it installs apc correctly, but with the wrong architecture. The article from Ralph Schindler is a good starting point. I'll check that. Thx

Comment: Nothing on the Ralph Schinlder article. It's still not working =/